# How to map values from Backend Nest JS to Frontend Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, mapping, nestjs, backend

Backend Nest JS Service Code:

```
async show(): Promise<any> {
  var response: dto = new dto();
  var data = await this.sequelize.query('Exec API_Select',
    {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    });
    if(data.length>0){
       data.map((item:any) =>  {  
        
        response.foo1=item.foo1;
        response.foo2=item.foo2;
        response.foo3=item.foo3;

       });
    return response;
    }
}
```

Frontend Angular Code (Service):

```
getdata(){
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization','Bearer'+' '+token);



this.http.post<interface1>('http://localhost:3000/getdata/',null,{headers})
    .pipe(map(data => ({
      foo1:data.foo1,
      foo2:data.foo2,
      foo3:data.foo3
    })))
    .subscribe(foo => console.log(foo))
}
```

Now if I give dummy values in e.g. `data.foo1` then it works (which means that the service and component code in Angular is fine. The Backend is also working fine since I can fetch data in Postman. The only problem is with mapping data from Backend to Frontend.

I have tried `.subscribe` instead of `.map` but it doesn't work. I have also tried it without `<interface1>` but still the result is same.

I am a beginner in this field and new to Nest JS and Angular. Please have a look. Thankyou.

Edit:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/getdata/',null,{headers}).subscribe(data => {
     this.dataout = data});
```

If I fetch the values as a single variable, e.g. in the above code, `data` is fetched, and in the Backend there is a variable `data`. then it also works fine. The only problem is with mapping.

API response from Postman:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isSuccess": true,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "foo1": 3,
            "foo2": "abc",
            "foo3": "def",
 
        },
        {
            "foo1": 1,
            "foo2": "ghi",
            "foo3": "jkl",

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping data"

Comment: It means to get exact values of variables from backend to frontend. E.g. I have ```foo1``` variable in the backend as ```response.foo1```, I want to retrieve that same variable value in the frontend to ```foo1``` which is ```data.foo1```. Similarly for ```foo2``` and ```foo3``` etc.

Comment: You're saying it work already doesn't it ?

Comment: No, mapping doesn't work. If I put dummy values for example ```foo1:12345``` instead of ```foo1:data.foo1``` then it works, which means that component and some of service code is fine. only the data is not getting mapped. The backend and frontend works completely fine if I get all the data as a single variable. but it doesn't work if i try to map values.

Comment: Please provide the postman result of your API reponses.

Comment: I have edited the Question, Please have a look the API response is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct syntax of your response

```js
this.http
  .post<interface1>('http://localhost:3000/getdata/',null,{headers})
    .pipe(map(({ data }) => ({
      foo1:data.foo1,
      foo2:data.foo2,
      foo3:data.foo3
    })))
    .subscribe(foo => console.log(foo))
}
```

Comment: Error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'interface1'

Comment: Then redo your interface1, or replace it with "any".

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you kindly tell how to redo interface? because I have to store values in the interface and fetch from there.